# Beautiful soup find href not working

Tags: regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm new into Python coding, but coded some simple scrapers so far with bs4. I'm having troubles with a particular project:

```
page = requests.get("http://www.radarindustrial.com.br/empresa/19640/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

web = soup.find_all(href = True, id = "contatos")
```

It returns [ ]. When I try only with

```
web = soup.find_all(id = "contatos")
```

It returns (correctly) div I need, it contains a single href (I've inserted the dot just to show the part of the code I need, which is that URL)

<.a href="/Redirect.aspx?cid=19640&url=http://www.ashtarbrindes.com.br" target="]

I've tried "web.a", find("a", id="contatos") and other ways but it returns an empty list or "none".

What am I messing up?

Comment: So, you need to get `a` tag that is inside `div` with `id` equal to `contatos`? Try `web =  soup.find("div", {"id": "contatos"}).select_one("a")`

Comment: Hey thanks, that works, now I just need to get the url inside the tag :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
>>> web = soup.find("div", {"id": "contatos"}).select_one('a["href"]')['href']
>>> web
'/Redirect.aspx?cid=19640&url=http://www.ashtarbrindes.com.br'
```

With `.find("div", {"id": "contatos"})` you will extract the `div` with `id` equal to `contatos`, then `.select_one('a["href"]')` will find the first `a` tag inside the `div` that contains `href` and `['href']` will access the `href` attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

Well if we're going to be ok with css, how about just:

```
soup.select_one('div#contatos a[href]')['href']
```